# MongoDB : one Read only secondary node pointing to two Primary nodes

Tags: mongodb

Recently I was trying with Mongo Replication for one of my project. I came across a scenario where in There will be 2 primary Instances of Mongo running. Each mongo will have one secondary and one arbitor(for Election Purpose). Now Can I introduce one read only mongo node which will act as secondary node for both Primary nodes. Below the Image of the Architecture Im thinking of
[One replice Pointing to 2 primary nodes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/65Zcl.png)

Is this Architecture Possible. If Possible is there any bottle neck or any point that we need to think of before choosing this point

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> I came across a scenario where in There will be 2 primary Instances of Mongo running.

You do not "run" primary nodes. You configure replica sets and each replica set elects a primary (if there are enough available voting members).

> Now Can I introduce one read only mongo node which will act as secondary node for both Primary nodes.

No, because each set is configured separately and a node in a replica set won't be part of other replica sets.